# React - Get data before rendering pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a situation where I need to fetch updated props within componentWillMount()

My Layout :

```js
@connect((store) => {
 //console.log(store);
 return {
       element: store.elements.elements,
       connections: store.connections.connections,
       attributes: store.attributes.attributes,
       media: store.media.media,
       places: store.places.places,
       user: store.user.user
 };
})

export default class Layout extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(fetchUser())
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.props.dispatch(updateStoreUser(nextProps.user))
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        console.log(nextProps);
        return true;
    }

  render() {
    const { location } = this.props;

    return (
          <div className="main-container">
              <Header/>
              <NavConnector/>
              {this.props.children}
          </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`{this.props.children}` will render pages depending on the route.

I have a `BasicInfo` Component :

```
componentWillMount() {
    console.log(this.props);        
    this.props.dispatch(fetchPlaces(1))
}
```

Where I need to pass user id to fetchPlaces, something like this `this.props.dispatch(fetchPlaces(this.props.user.id)`

But this.props does not have user.id yet, in the `componentWillReceiveProps` of the layout I'm updating the store, but gets updated after componentWillMount() of `BasicInfo` component is called.

The console log :

[image]

**UPDATE**

I have a connector for `BasicInfo`, `this.props.user` inside the render method is always undefined. But the store has the user values by now.

Is there any way to pass data from Layout? The place where `{this.props.children}` is being called? Because that's where the `BasicInfoConnector` is being called.

```js
import React from "react"
import * as Redux from 'react-redux';
import Basicinfo from "./Basicinfo"

const mapStateToProps = function (store) {
    return {
        elements: store.elements.elements,
        places: store.places.places,
        geocode : store.geocode.geocode,
        user : store.user.user
    };
};

class BasicinfoConnector extends React.Component{

  render() {
      console.log(this.props.user);
    return (
        <BasicInfoConnector elements={this.props.elements} places={this.props.places} geocode={this.props.geocode} user={this.props.user}/>
    );
  }
}

export default Redux.connect(mapStateToProps)(BasicinfoConnector);
```

Client JS

```js
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from "react-router"
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import { useScrollToTop } from "scroll-behavior"
import store from "./store"

import '../styles/sass/master/global.scss'

import Layout from "./components/Layout";
import Alerts from "./components/Dashboard/Alerts/Alerts"
import AttributesConnector from "./components/Dashboard/Attributes/AttributesConnector"
import BasicInfoConnector from "./components/Dashboard/Basicinfo/BasicinfoConnector"
import ConnectionsConnector from "./components/Dashboard/Connections/ConnectionsConnector"
import MediaConnector from "./components/Dashboard/Media/MediaConnector"
import Stats from "./components/Dashboard/Stats/Stats"

const app = document.getElementById('app')

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router histroy={hashHistory} onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)}>
            <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
                <IndexRoute component={BasicInfoConnector}></IndexRoute>
                <Route path="location" component={BasicInfoConnector}></Route>
                <Route path="alerts" component={Alerts}></Route>
                <Route path="attributes" component={AttributesConnector}></Route>
                <Route path="connections" component={ConnectionsConnector}></Route>
                <Route path="media" component={MediaConnector}></Route>
                <Route path="stats" component={Stats}></Route>
            </Route>
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
app);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want to fetch places in componentWillMount, the only solution is to not render the component at all using conditional rendering until the user id is available since componentWillMount gets called only once. Something like this:

```
{this.props.user?<BasicInfo />:null}
```

Update:

You need to export a component which is connected (subscribed) to redux store. You are exporting the component which is not connected yet. Just remove the `export default` before the component declaration

```
class BasicinfoConnector extends React.Component
```

and add an export default before the connect statement.

```
export default Redux.connect(mapStateToProps)(BasicinfoConnector);
```

This should fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks Swapnil, can you check the updated question. Your answer makes sense to me, but still has some trouble solving.

Comment: Are you able to access other props i.e. elements, places and geocode inside render method or are they also undefined?

Comment: even they are undefined. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think the line **const BasicInfoConnector = Redux.connect(mapStateToProps)(Basicinfo);** is incorrect. I am updating my anwer in a min

Comment: Now its not loading anything on the page, in console I get error saying : `client.js:13 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./components/Dashboard/Basicinfo/BasicinfoConnector"` 

Anything else could be wrong?

Comment: Line 13 of client.js : `import BasicInfoConnector from "./components/Dashboard/Basicinfo/BasicinfoConnector"`

Comment: Means there is an error in this file. You gotta somehow find out the error and tell me. Or if possible share you code-base

Comment: Ah damn I am stupid. Updated my answer. Check the export statement again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132531/discussion-between-swapnil-and-deepak-bandi).

Comment: Sure Swapnil. Have some errors, have shared in the chat.